# How to Get week data in object form in react Js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am playing with dates using moment js, I got all months value and year also but, problem is I have to detect week data

I marked reactangle for week that I want

[image: 1]

like tha above Image and getting all week data like this Image
i.e Currently **jan** month , suppose jan month have 4 week so I want 4 week with all dates and days like above Image format

1. I want week data with dates and days just like which I marked in  above Image in React
2. I want get week Data in the object like record   {o:moment_ , 1:moment_ , 2:moment_}

Comment: have you tried the `.week()` function on the `Moment` object?

Comment: Yes, but its returns only the current moment week.

Comment: if you create a moment object with another date like `moment('2022-01-01').week()` then it gives the week of the given date.